# Does MIMIC-III have imaging data? If so, how can i access it?

Tags: mimic-iii

The MIMIC-III data download consists of csv files. Publications such as http://www.nature.com/articles/sdata201635 mention that reports of imaging studies are available. However, I wanted to know if the images are available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imaging reports are currently available (as of MIMIC-III v1.3), but the images themselves are not. It is possible that images will be released at a later date, but we do not expect this to happen in the near future due to the challenges of preparing imaging data for release (for example, robust deidentification), as well as resource limitations (for example, researcher and clinician time).

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is a database in mimic with x-ray images. 
You can find more information about this in:

- [News about the dataset](http://news.mit.edu/2019/mimic-chest-x-ray-database-0201)
- [Get the dataset](https://physionet.org/physiobank/database/mimiccxr/)